# Store data in diff. JSON files through Loop using Python

Tags: python, json, api, pycharm, python-3.9

**I'm using API call through which I get data in every iteration but the issue is I'm confused that how I can save data in JSON file of every iteration.**

**language : Python**

**Version : 3.9**

```
import virustotal_python
from pprint import pprint

folder_path = 'C:/Users/E-TIME/PycharmProjects/FYP script/263 Hascodes in Txt Format'
count = 0
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt')):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read()
        l = lines.split(" ")
        l = l[0].split('\n')
        for file_id in range(0,3):
            with virustotal_python.Virustotal(
                    "ab8421085f362f075cc88cb1468534253239be0bc482da052d8785d422aaabd7") as vtotal:
                resp = vtotal.request(f"files/{l[file_id]}/behaviours")
                data = resp.data
                pprint(data)
```

Comment: Write() function is what you need to check: https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-text-file/

Comment: What is your expected output?